# stop timer that using @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple job that using Spring Boot with scheduler annotation, it runs successfully but how can I pause or stop it?

```
@Component
public class UpAndDown {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void upAndDown() {}
}
```

Comment: under what conditions you want to stop or pause?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have a flag that keeps track of whether this functionality is enabled or not. Then, check that flag in your method:

```
@Component
public class UpAndDown {
    private boolean triggerEnabled = true;

    public void setTriggerEnabled(boolean triggerEnabled) {
        this.triggerEnabled = triggerEnabled;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void upAndDown() {
        if(triggerEnabled) {
            doTheStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

This will obviously not stop the timer, but it will effectively do what you want it to do, without messing with the infrastructure beans.